# Can't open zip file created from System.IO.Compression namespace

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-core, system.io.compression

I'm trying to zip varying amounts of files so that one zip folder can be served to the user instead of them having to click multiple anchor tags. I am using the System.IO.Compression namespace in asp.net core 3.1 to create the zip folder.

Here is the code I'm using to create the Zip folder.

```
        public IActionResult DownloadPartFiles(string[] fileLocations, string[] fileNames)
        {
            List<InMemoryFile> files = new List<InMemoryFile>();
            for (int i = 0; i < fileNames.Length; i++)
            {
                InMemoryFile inMemoryFile = GetInMemoryFile(fileLocations[i], fileNames[i]).Result;
                files.Add(inMemoryFile);
            }
            byte[] archiveFile;
            using (MemoryStream archiveStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(archiveStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
                {
                    foreach (InMemoryFile file in files)
                    {
                        ZipArchiveEntry zipArchiveEntry = archive.CreateEntry(file.FileName, CompressionLevel.Fastest);
                        using (Stream zipStream = zipArchiveEntry.Open())
                        {
                            zipStream.Write(file.Content, 0, file.Content.Length);
                            zipStream.Close();
                        }
                    }
                    archiveStream.Position = 0;
                }
                archiveFile = archiveStream.ToArray();
            }

            return File(archiveFile, "application/octet-stream");
        }
```

The files I am trying to zip are stored remotely so I grab them with this block of code. The InMemoryFile is a class to group the file name and file bytes together.

```
        private async Task<InMemoryFile> GetInMemoryFile(string fileLocation, string fileName)
        {
            InMemoryFile file;
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(fileLocation))
            {
                byte[] fileContent = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
                file = new InMemoryFile(fileName, fileContent);
            }
            return file;
        }
```

The DownloadPartFiles method is called using Ajax. I grab the remote paths to the files and their respective names using javascript and pass them into the Ajax call.

```
function downloadAllFiles() {
    let partTable = document.getElementById("partTable");
    let linkElements = partTable.getElementsByTagName('a');
    let urls = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < linkElements.length; i++) {
        urls.push(linkElements[i].href);
    }

    if (urls.length != 0) {

        var fileNames = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < linkElements.length; i++) {
            fileNames.push(linkElements[i].innerText);
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/WebOrder/DownloadPartFiles/",
            data: { 'fileLocations': urls, 'fileNames': fileNames },
            success: function (response) {
                var blob = new Blob([response], { type: "application/zip" });
                var link = document.createElement('a');
                link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                link.download = "PartFiles.zip";
                link.click();
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(blob);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now the issue I keep running into is that I can't open the zip folder within Windows 10. Every time I try to open the zip folder using Windows or 7-zip I get an error message that the folder can't be opened or the folder is invalid. I've tried looking at various similar issues on stackoverflow, ie [Invalid zip file after creating it with System.IO.Compression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40175391/invalid-zip-file-after-creating-it-with-system-io-compression), but still can't figure out why this is.

Could it be the encoding? I found that Ajax expects its responses to be encoded UTF-8 and when I view the zip file using notepad++ with UTF-8 I see that there are � characters indicating corruption.

Any thoughts on this would be helpful. Let me know if more information is needed.

If one of the corrupt zip files is needed I can provide that as well.

**Edit:**

I have since changed my method of receiving the byte array in javascript. I am using a XMLHttpRequest to receive the byte array.

```
        var parameters = {};
        parameters.FileLocations = urls;
        parameters.FileNames = fileNames;

        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("POST", "/WebOrder/DownloadPartFiles/", true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        xmlhttp.responseType = "arraybuffer";

        xmlhttp.onload = function (oEvent) {
            var arrayBuffer = xmlhttp.response;
            if (arrayBuffer) {
                var byteArray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
                var blob = new Blob([byteArray], { type: "application/zip" });
                var link = document.createElement('a');
                link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                link.download = "PartFiles.zip";
                link.click();
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(blob);
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(parameters));
```

From what I read, Ajax is not the best for receiving byte arrays and binary data. With this method I was able to open one of the zip file with 7-zip, but not Windows, however, one of the files within the archive was showing as a size of 0KB and couldn't be opened. The other three files in the archive were fine. Other zip folders with different files could not be opened at all though.

Comment: Did you debug this in so far as to make sure the data you're sending via POST request is properly received? Also, why does it say `dataType: "html",` in the request params?

Comment: Yes, the fileLocations and fileNames are coming through fine. As for the dataType that was a mistake on my end. I removed that but am still getting the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time I found a post that was able to fix my issue, [Create zip file from byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17217077/create-zip-file-from-byte)

From that post this is the revised method I'm using to create a zip folder with files in it.

```
        public IActionResult DownloadPartFiles([FromBody] FileRequestParameters parameters)
        {
            List<InMemoryFile> files = new List<InMemoryFile>();
            for (int i = 0; i < parameters.FileNames.Length; i++)
            {
                InMemoryFile inMemoryFile = GetInMemoryFile(parameters.FileLocations[i], parameters.FileNames[i]).Result;
                files.Add(inMemoryFile);
            }
            byte[] archiveFile = null;
            using (MemoryStream archiveStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(archiveStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
                {
                    foreach (InMemoryFile file in files)
                    {
                        ZipArchiveEntry zipArchiveEntry = archive.CreateEntry(file.FileName, CompressionLevel.Optimal);
                        using (MemoryStream originalFileStream = new MemoryStream(file.Content))
                        using (Stream zipStream = zipArchiveEntry.Open())
                        {
                            originalFileStream.CopyTo(zipStream);
                        }
                    }
                }
                archiveFile = archiveStream.ToArray();
            }
            return File(archiveFile, "application/octet-stream");
        }
```

I still don't know why the previous method was having issues so if anyone knows the answer to that in the future I'd love to know.